# mpicc-vt: command not found

Tags: c, ubuntu, mpi, openmpi

I had installed `openmpi-bin`, `openmpi-common`, `libopenmpi-dev` on ubuntu 16.10. 
Command `mpicc` is working, but I get `mpicc-vt: command not found`. 
The binary `mpicc` is located in folder `/usr/bin/`. Where I can find `mpicc-vt`?

Comment: Did you check `/usr/lib/openmpi/bin/`?

Comment: There is no such folder.
`cd /usr/lib/openmpi/` ->`ls` ->` include  lib`

Comment: [Manual](https://tu-dresden.de/zih/forschung/ressourcen/dateien/laufende-projekte/vampirtrace/dateien/VT-UserManual-5.14.4.pdf?lang=en) states that VampirTrace is included in Open MPI 1.3 and later versions. If not disabled explicitly, VampirTrace is built automatically when installing Open MPI. So what is your OpenMPI version?

Comment: I have OpenMPI 2.1.0.

Comment: I have tried to reconfigure with flag  `--with-contrib-vt-flags` and recompile, but all for nothing

Comment: I also cannot find VampireTrace in source files. I do not understand why they say it is included. You can try to install VampireTrace externally from this [link](https://tu-dresden.de/zih/forschung/projekte/vampirtrace).

Comment: Okay, I'll do it, but it all seems strange.

Comment: In this [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-mpi/ompi/v2.x/NEWS) it is written that VampirTrace is removed from OpenMPI since 12/July/2016.

Answer (score 2):

VampirTrace has been removed from OpenMPI with Version 2.0, as it is no longer actively developed. You can manually install [Score-P](http://www.score-p.org/), the successor of VampirTrace, or manually install the [last release of VampirTrace](http://wwwpub.zih.tu-dresden.de/%7Emlieber/dcount/dcount.php?package=vampirtrace&get=VampirTrace-5.14.4.tar.gz).

If you use Score-P, the equivalent compiler command to `mpicc-vt` is basically:

```
scorep mpicc
```